# Question about functions and topology

Tags: general-topology, functions

This is a very general question, but one that I have been struggling with. If we say that a function from a topological space X to a topological space Y is ONTO, then does that mean that for each open set A in Y there is an open set V in X such that f(V)=A, or does it just carry the normal definition that we use in elementary function theory(the definition using points). I know this is an extremely elementary question, but it just happens to be so elementary that I cannot find an adequate answer online.

Comment: I think you are confusing *continuity* and *surjectivity*.  A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if $V\subset Y$ is open $\Rightarrow f^{-1}(V)\subset X$ is open.  Surjectivity on the other hand simply requires that $f(X)=Y$, but does not require that preimages of open sets be open.

Comment: Well see that is why I am confused, because that reason was the exact reason why I was pretty sure that my definition was not correct, but then does that mean that a function being from two topological spaces just carries the normal definition if it is onto? I think I am just confused because I thought that a function between two topological spaces was acting upon open sets, since they are just collections of open sets, instead of points like a normal function.

Comment: If you are working in topological spaces, you are almost always working with continuous functions (so much so that they often don't bother including that the function is continuous as a hypothesis each time they write a problem, but instead as a side-note in the first or zeroth chapter).  Even so, D181 below gave an example of a map between topological spaces which although is surjective, is not continuous and does not satisfy the requirement that preimages of open sets be open.  Other examples of non-continuous functions that you learned in precalc will provide additional counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

If the function $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous and onto, then the following statement is true:

> for every open set $A$ in $Y$, there exists an open set $V$ in $X$ such that $f(V)=A$.

How do we show this? Let $A$ be open in $Y$. By the continuity of $f$, we know that $V=f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$. Since $f$ is onto (or surjective, it's the same concept), then $f(V)=A$.

Indeed, if $x\in V=f^{-1}(A)$, then $f(x)\in A$, by definition. If $y\in A$, then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in V$, because $f$ is onto. Then $x\in V=f^{-1}(A)$ and so $y=f(x)\in f(V)$.

If the function $f$ is not continuous this can be true or false, depending on $f$. For instance, consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and $Y=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x$ is rational}\\[6px]
1 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $A=\{0\}$ is open in $Y$, but there exists no open set $V$ in $X$ such that $f(V)=A$, because no subset of the rationals is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

It referees only to the normal set theoretic definition of onto map. For example you can have a bijection(hence an onto map), such as the identity set theoretic map, between $\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial topology and $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology but it does not satisfy that for each open set in the second space you have an open set in the first one such as its image is the initial open set in the second space.